# Button in LCDUI for Symbian S60 5th edition

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, symbian, nokia

Hi I am an Android developer but I am new to development on Symbian. I couldn't find any classes to put a button on the form. How do I do it on Symbian. Am not sure whether I am doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TextItem and set its style to button.
This is a pure J2me thing and has nothing specifically to do with Symbian